# Connection timeout with Zend_Db::factory using PDO_MYSQL

Tags: php, pdo, zend-db, connection-timeout

What is the proper (or better) way to set connection timeout with PHP code, when using Zend_Db::factory with PDO_MYSQL.

I have:

```
$params = array (
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'dbname'    => 'mydb',
    'charset'   => 'UTF8',
);

$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
```

a.)

```
$db->getConnection()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 600);
```

b.)

```
$sql = "SET SESSION wait_timeout = 600";
$db->getConnection()->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the connection timeout to 3 seconds:

```
$params = array (
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'dbname'    => 'mydb',
    'charset'   => 'UTF8',
    'driver_options' => [
        \PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 3
    ]
);

$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
```